# which tool could i use to write python with app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Currently I am writing my python code with Textwrangler. so if I want to check my code I deploy or check it on the localhost, and if there is an error so i should found it by my self, Is there a tool that could help me ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "Run locally" section of the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/).

Also, IDE might help checking the code:
Eclipse with Aptana (google: Eclipse Aptana App Engine).
IntelliJ (google: IntelliJ Python App Engine).